# SSIS - Create a CSV file from 2 different OLE DB sources

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I'm looking for a way in SSIS (2005) to create a CSV file from 2 or more different layout OLE DB sources. Again, the column layout is different for all the sources.

EX.

*Source 1*
**A,1234,ABCD,1234**

*Source 2*
**A,ABCD,1234**

*Final CSV Result File*
**A,1234,ABCD,1234

A,ABCD,1234**

Comment: Does it matter about the ordering? i.e. all data from "A" must be together or can it be 'whole of source A' followed by  'whole of source B'

Comment: I need to add sources to the resulting file in a specific order. Resulting file must have all records from Source1 and then all records from Source2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of options.  You could combine the results from your inputs into one column and include commas in your data and then merge the two sources together.  It's not a great solution, but it would meet your business needs as stated.

Comment: This is what I ultimately ended doing. I was looking for something more elegant though.

Answer (score 0):

Combine the two inputs with a Union All component leading to your Destination component. In the union, you'll have to choose which input columns should go to which output columns.

Comment: columns do not match between the 2 sources. UNION works with identic column/data type definition.

Comment: My current environment doesn't do BI, so I couldn't finish this one for you. But I bet if you add dummy columns to each data flow, you could make it work.